# How to build Boost with C++0x support?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, bjam

I don't know how to build Boost with C++0x compilers. Which option must be given to bjam? Should the user.config file be modified?Can someone help me?

Best,
Vicente

Comment: Wanted to note that as of boost 1.48 and gcc-4.5, compiling with c++0x is necessary for libraries such as boost::filesystem. Otherwise functions like copy_file are not found at linking.

Comment: They will work if you define the macro : ``#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS`` before the include of ``filesystem.hpp``

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have found the answer. I was waiting for a features something like 'std' and call it as follows:

```
bjam std=0x
```

but currently we need to use the low level variables cxxflags and add the specific compiler flags. For example for gcc we can do

```
bjam toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=gnu++0x
```

Other compilers will need a different setting.

Waiting for a new Boost.Build feature, you can also define your own toolset as follows: Add the user.config or site.config file

```
using gcc
   : std0x
   : "/usr/bin/g++" # your path to the C++0x compiler
   : <cxxflags>-std=gnu++0x
   ;
```

And now call as

```
bjam toolset=gcc-std0x
```

Comment: With newer versions of boost it is ./b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=gnu++0x. With newer versions of gcc, use -std=gnu++11

Comment: With newer versions, you can use `std=c++11` if you don't want to enable the GNU extensions.

Answer (score 12):

To compile using clang, use the `cxxflags` and `linkflags`:

```
./b2 \
    ...
    cxxflags="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++" \
    linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" \
    ...
```

Passing a `-v` to `cxxflags` is also helpful when debugging.

Answer (score 12):

**Use something like this:**

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc --prefix=/usr/local

./b2 -j12 toolset=gcc variant=release link=shared threading=multi address-model=64 cxxflags=-std=c++11 install
```

The -j12  is for parallel (12 threads) build
use `-std=c++11` for better compatibility and  `-std=gnu++11` for the gnu extensions (only for gcc)

if boost::mpi is not build (see the output of above command) -> edit the user-config.jam

if you want to build only certain components:
add:

```
--with-libraries=system,thread,serialization
```

for example

Here is an adapted script from my [framework](http://gabyx.github.io/GRSFramework/) from travis (adjust `ROOT_PATH`):

```
BOOST_DOWNLOAD_URL="http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.58.0/boost_1_58_0.tar.bz2/download"
BOOST_BUILD=${ROOT_PATH}/boostBuild
mkdir -p ${BOOST_BUILD}
wget --no-verbose --output-document="${ROOT_PATH}/boost.tar.bz2" "$BOOST_DOWNLOAD_URL"
cd ${BOOST_BUILD}
tar jxf "${ROOT_PATH}/boost.tar.bz2" --strip-components=1 -C "${BOOST_BUILD}"
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc --with-libraries=system,thread,serialization,filesystem,chrono,atomic,date_time
sudo ./b2 -j12 toolset=gcc threading=multi link=shared release install
```

which installs into `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 3):

I came across an article for compiling Boost using clang: http://blog.llvm.org/2010/05/clang-builds-boost.html. It might be possible to adapt the changes proposed there for compiling Boost using Boost.Jam to your favorite C++0x compiler.

Comment: Hi, I don't see nothing in this page related to c++0x. Please could you clarify your response?

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can [change compilation flags for one file](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/faq/s08.html) like this:

`exe test : test.cpp : <cxxflags>-std=gnu++0x ;`