# Bjam how to print include path used in compiling

Tags: c++, bjam

I have a Jamroot.jam for a big project. I want to print all paths where g++ searches for includes when compiling, how can i do this (normally `-v` flag in g++) ? I try `bjam --debug-configuration`  but it doesn't do what i ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here:

[How to build Boost with C++0x support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887707/how-to-build-boost-with-c0x-support)

To compile using clang, use the cxxflags and linkflags:

```
./bjam \
...
cxxflags="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++" \
linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" \
...
```

Passing a -v to cxxflags is also helpful when debugging.